# How to Display Records of Table together in Stimulsoft

Tags: record, tabular, stimulsoft

I use Stimulsoft reports. I want to display records of my table in boxes together. Like floated div in html or like RepeatColumns in DataList in asp.net control. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution .That is what I want:
[Report with Columns in Data Band](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/index.html?getting_started_report_with_columns_in_data_band.htm)